# First PCB layout but can't validate yet

Tags: pcb-design, voltage-regulator, relay, esp32

I'm learning some basic circuitry with an ESP32 Dev Kit and copied some schematics online to connect the ESP32 to external power, a relay and an input reed switch sensor.  My problem is I'm still awaiting for the relay, transistor and linear voltage regulator from Adafruit to test all of this.

Can someone have a look and provide thoughts, feedback and validation to a newbie please?

[image: Schematic]

[image: PCB]

Comment: If CN3 is reed switch connector, the switch will short 5V to ground. Otherwise the question is pretty open-ended and has no definitive answer, as it asks for thoughts and feedback, which may be opinion-based.

Comment: Don’t go switching mains voltages with that relay as you violate safety creepage distances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few thoughts...

If you want some good advice, make your 0 volts into a full ground-plane on the underside (blue) of the PCB. Also thicken up top-side power tracks that might be handling several hundred (or more) milliamps of current. You can slip the odd blue track onto the ground-plane and cause hardly any disruption to the ground-plane but, keep those tracks as short as possible.

You will also need input and output capacitors on your 5 volt regulator (read the 7805 data sheet and it will make that clear to you).

Adding 100 nF decoupling capacitors from 5 volts to 0 volts close to the power pins for the main device is also something you will need to get into the habit of doing. The ground-plane (0 volts) acts as a near-ideal return path for this.

You should also (possibly) apply greater distances between relay contact tracks and tracks associated with the 5 volt circuits in order to meet the voltage spacing criteria of supplies and loads on the relay contact circuits.

Bring unused pins on the two headers out to test points so that if you need to make modifications (or add circuitry), you have a simple way to solder wires. Make your PCB as future-proof as you can in other words.

Comment: maybe add 100µF close to the ESP32 - it's known for its current spikes and sensitivity to voltage drops.

Comment: hey guys I just wanted to say thanks so much for your feedback and suggestions, they're incredibly helpful. I'll take these points on for the PCB design and test the rest of the circuitry when the parts arrive.